# Montando updates em tempo de execução

Tags: java, c#, sql, banco-de-dados, delphi

Ao montar `SELECTS` em tempo de execução temos sempre o problema de saber o que pode estar vindo ou não em função das escolhas feitas pelo usuário.

Ao montar a clausula `WHERE` nos deparamos com a questão de adicionar ou não o `AND` antes de cada condição.

Se for a primeira condição então não terá o `AND`, no entanto se for a segunda ou maior que isso adicionamos ao inicio da condição `AND`.

Para não ficar refém dessa condição, tendo que analisá-la em todos os momentos eu adiciono uma clausula inócua e então posso adicionar `AND` à todas as outras.

Desse modo minha clausula `WHERE` inicial é `WHERE 0 = 0`, então posso adicionar o `AND` à todas as outras condições.

No momento da execução minha clausula `WHERE` estará assim: `WHERE 0 = 0 AND condicao1 = 'cond1' AND condicao2 = 'cond2' AND condicao3 = 3` ou simplesmente assim: `WHERE 0 = 0` e funcionará sem problemas.

Quando montamos um `UPDATE` em tempo de execução temos o mesmo problema, porém a questão agora é a virgula ou a falta total de parâmetros.

Começamos com `"UPDATE tabelax SET"` e vamos adicionando colunas a medida que o programa for encontrando essas marcações.

Na primeira adicionamos `"campo1 = 'campo1'" + ","`, na segunda `"campo2 = 'campo2' + ","`. Veja que não poderíamos adicionar a vírgula caso o campo2 fosse o ultimo campo preenchido porque senão nosso comando final ficaria errado. `UPDATE tabelax SET campo1 = 'campo1', campo2 = 'campo2', WHERE condicao` esta errado. Ou seja tem de ficar questionando se é o ultimo ou não, ou então adicionar em todos e ao terminar o laço verificar se o ultimo caractere é um virgula e tirá-la antes de adicionar a clausula `WHERE`.

Enfim, a pergunta: não tem um maneira, como o caso do `WHERE`, 
que fique mais fácil, mais elegante ou seja inteligente de resolver isso?

Comment: Em que linguagem está montando a *query*?

Comment: SQL-Server ou Oracle

Comment: Não use CAPSLOCK sem necessidade.

Comment: Você monta a *query* dentro de *stored procedure*?

Comment: Não. A query é executada no client mesmo, via TSimpleDataSet.

Comment: Então seria Delphi?

Comment: Pode ser. Mas não somente Delphi. Escrevo isso em Delphi, C# e Java também.

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta está um pouco ampla ainda. Falta um exemplo efetivo do problema. Do jeito que está, a resposta do Ricardo abrange a maioria dos casos.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minha técnica é usar uma variável para representar o separador e sempre concatenar o próximo valor depois do separador; mas o separador é inicializado vazio e só recebe o texto de separação depois que o primeiro valor for adicionado à query.

Em um **loop**, fica mais ou menos assim:

```
sql = "update tabela set ";
paramPattern = "%s = '%s'";
separador = "";

// campos a atualizar, separados por vírgula:

for(campo : campos) {
    sql += separador + String.format(paramPattern, campo.nome, campo.valor);
    separador = ", ";
}

// cláusula where:

sql += " where ";
separador = "";

for(condicao : condicoes) {
    sql += separador + condicao;
    separador = " and ";
}
```

A idéia serve também se você não tiver listas de campos e de condições mas em vez disso usa **if**s. Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
sql = "update tabela set ";
paramPattern = "%s = '%s'";
separador = "";

// campos a atualizar, separados por vírgula:

if (atualizarCampo1) {
    sql += separador + String.format(paramPattern, campo1.nome, campo1.valor);
    separador = ", ";
}
if (atualizarCampo2) {
    sql += separador + String.format(paramPattern, campo2.nome, campo2.valor);
    separador = ", ";
}
// outros campos...

// cláusula where:

sql += " where ";
separador = "";

if (filtrarPorData) {
    sql += separador + "DATA between :data1 and :data2";
    separador = " AND ";
}
if (filtrarPorStatus) {
    sql += separador + "STATUS = :status";
    separador = " AND ";
}
// outras condições...
```

Se houver possibilidade de não haver nenhum filtro (comando sem cláusula *where*), basta preencher as condições em outra variável, e só concatená-la ao sql caso ela termine diferente de vazia depois de passar por todas as tratativas de condições. Por exemplo:

```
sql = "select * from tabela";
where = "";
separador = "";

if (filtrarPorData) {
    where += separador + "DATA between :data1 and :data2";
    separador = " AND ";
}
if (filtrarPorStatus) {
    where += separador + "STATUS = :status";
    separador = " AND ";
}
// outras condições...

if (!"".equals(where)) {
    sql += " where " + where;
}
```

Eu prefiro fazer assim do que adicionar algo na query (*where 1=1*) apenas por fisiologia do código. E também prefiro assim do que adicionar algo desnecessário na string para depois remover (no caso, uma vírgula extra).

<sub>E é claro que este é um pseudo código só para demonstrar a idéia do separador como variável. Espero que você use sempre parâmetros em vez de concatenar valores na query.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Em C# use o método [`Join()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___), ele vai montar colocando o separador do jeito correto.

Em Java use o método [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-).

Não sei se Delphi moderno tem algo pronto, mas é fácil fazer um `Join()`:

```
function Join(const Texts : array of string; const Separator : string) : string;
var
    i : Integer;
begin
    Result := Texts[low(Texts)];
    for i := low(Texts) + 1 to high(Texts) do
        Result := Separator + Result + Texts[i];
end;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/QueryBuilder.pas).

Note que ele começa pegando o primeiro elemento do *array* antes do laço (este é o segredo pra não deixar um separador sobrando) e depois coloca sempre um par de separador e novo item.

Comment: Para utilizar essa função eu precisaria criar esse array dinâmico todas as vezes de montar esses updates, portanto não me parece mais fácil do que estou fazendo. De qualquer forma a função não me parece uma má ideia. Fiz uma alteração para funcionar e ficou assim:

function Join(const Texts : array of string; const Separator : string) : string;
var
    i : Integer;
begin
    for i := low(Texts) to high(Texts) do
    begin
      Result := Result + Texts[i];
      if ( i < high(Texts) ) then
        Result := Result + Separator;
    end
end;

Answer (score 2):

Com base nesta [reposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891075/5429980) fiz uma adaptação para você que permite montar o `update` em tempo de execução, veja como ficou:

```
static string buildUpdate(string table, string nomeCampoId, string idCampo, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{           
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Update " + table + " SET ");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> param in parameters)            
        builder.Append(param.Key).Append(" = ").Append(param.Value).Append(",");            

    builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1); /*Aqui remove a virgula.*/
    builder.Append(" WHERE ").Append(nomeCampoId).Append(" = ").Append(idCampo);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Para utilizar o método `buildUpdate()` é necessário construir seu dicionário para popular ele com os campos e os valores, veja como ficou a implementação:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("campoNome", "'Maria'");
    parameters.Add("campoIdade", 25);
    parameters.Add("campoGenero", "'Feminino'");

    string update = buildUpdate("Pessoa", "idPessoa", "2",parameters);
    Console.WriteLine(update);
}
```

O método `buildUpdate()` vai gerar a seguinte saída no console:

> Update Pessoa SET campoNome = 'Maria',campoIdade = 25,campoGenero =
>   'Feminino' WHERE idPessoa = 2

Você vai precisar adapta-lo, mas acredito que já é um caminho.

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo adicionar as condições com a vírgula, e no final removo o ultimo caractere da string.
No caso do AND funciona da mesma forma só que removendo 3 caracteres.

```
public String constroiCondicao1(String... condicoes){
    if(condicoes == null)
        return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("WHERE ");
    for(String cond : condicoes){
        sb.append(cond + " AND ");
    }
    return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length()-4);
}

// OU

public String constroiCondicao2(String... condicoes){
    if(condicoes == null)
        return "";
    return "WHERE " + String.join(" AND ", condicoes);
}
```

Comment: No caso do AND, ele não fica no final da string, mas entre as condições. 

WHERE 0 = 0 AND condicao1 = 'cond1' AND condicao2 = 'cond2' AND condicao3 = 3

A questão é que sem o 0 = 0 temos que testar se é a primeira condição que estamos inserindo ou não.

Comment: Neste caso não seria necessário utilizar o 0 = 0, então o AND ficaria no final.

Comment: Hmmm. Você esta fazendo de maneira diferente da que faço e diferente do que sugere a pergunta.

Vejamos, eu faço assim: 

Inicio com uma string, digamos clausulaWhere  =  'WHERE 0 = 0 ' e entro no loop

Digamos que o usuario tenha informado a condicao 1, 
    o programa adiciona o AND e a condicao1 
Digamos que o usuario tenha informado a condicao 2, 
    o programa adiciona o AND e a condicao2

Comment: Voce faz assim: 

Inicia com uma string, digamos clausulaWhere  =  'WHERE '  e entra no loop

Digamos que o usuario tenha informado a condicao 1, 
    o programa adiciona a condicao1 e o AND
Digamos que o usuario tenha informado a condicao 2, 
    o programa adiciona a condicao2 e o AND

No final verifica se a ultima palavra é um AND e retira.  

Mas se não tiver entrado nenhuma condição o WHERE fica solitario, por isso o 0 = 0 
inicial.

Comment: Editei minha resposta para um maior entendimento. Existem várias formas de se fazer, ai você pode adaptar melhor para a sua realidade.